# Conditional rendering of JSX based on JSON value not matching

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the below JSON:

```
{
    title: "Title 1",
    submenu: [
       {
           col: 1,
           title: "Sub Title 1",
        },
        {
          col: 1,
          title: "Sub Title 2",
        },
        {
          col: 2,
          title: "Sub Title 3",
        },
}
```

And I am trying to show different content each time the

```
col
```

value changes

Here is what I have so far:

```
{props.siteLinks.map((item, key) => (
    {item.title}
    {item.submenu.map((subitem, key) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li key={subitem.title}>
                        {subitem.col}
                        {subitem.title}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         )
     })}
))}
```

I would like to change

```
{subitem.col}
```

So when the value changes e.g. col:1 to col:2 a new div is inserted

Desired output would be:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>Column 1</div>
            Sub title 1
            Sub title 2
            <div>Column 2</div>
            Sub title 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to do a group by, on col.  take a look at this url for more information on groupby

https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Given this json:

```
{
    title: "Title 1",
    submenu: [
       {
           col: 1,
           title: "Sub Title 1",
        },
        {
          col: 1,
          title: "Sub Title 2",
        },
        {
          col: 2,
          title: "Sub Title 3",
        },
}
```

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
    return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
      var key = obj[property];
      if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = [];
      }
      acc[key].push(obj);
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

const distinctVals = groupBy(subitem, 'col');
```

Produces

```
distinctVals =
    {
        1: [
            {
                col: 1,
                title: "Sub Title 1",
            },
            {
                col: 1,
                title: "Sub Title 2",
            }
        ],
        2: [
            {
                col: 1,
                title: "Sub Title 1",
            }
        ]
    }
```

So now you can use that to map the columns:

```
props.siteLinks.map((item, key) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                distinctVals.map((val, key) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                {val.map((v, ind) => {
                                    <li key={ind}>
                                        {val.col}
                                        {val.title}
                                    </li>
                                })
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer after reading @Jon Jones post below. He linked a groupBy method using array.prototype.reduce(), and I provided an example of this.